# Searching data MongoDB/php

Tags: php, mongodb

I can display  collections from mongodb acording the input entry using php with codes below. When data entered in input field is not matched with any collection i want to display **This name is not found in database **. I got stuck here, the message can't display.

```
require_once('mongo_config.php');
 $searchtext = $_GET["name"];
 $get_users1 = $c_users->find(array('firstname'=> array('$regex' =>  $searchtext)));

if(empty($get_users1))
{
echo 'This name is not found in database !';    
}
if(!empty($get_users1)){
  echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><th>firstname</th><th>lastname</th><th></th><th></tr>';
   foreach($get_users1 as $user)
    {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $user['firstname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $user['lastname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="update_user.php?edit=' . $user['_id'] . '">Modifier</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="delete_user.php?delete='.$user['_id'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this user ?\')">Supprimer</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
       echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
}
```

I would like to get help to display the message when no data is found in database.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use else?

```
if($c_users->count()>0){
  echo '<table>
            <tr>
                <th>firstname</th>
                <th>lastname</th>
                <th></th><th>
            </tr>';
   foreach($get_users1 as $user)
   {
      echo '<tr>
             <td>' . $user['firstname'] . '</td>
             <td>' . $user['lastname'] . '</td>
             <td><a href="update_user.php?edit=' . $user['_id'] . '">Modifier</td>
             <td><a href="delete_user.php?delete='.$user['_id'].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this user ?\')">Supprimer</td>
            </tr>';
   }
        echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo 'This name is not found in database !';    
}
```

Comment: What if you change the `empty($get_users1)` to `empty($c_users)` ? (i've never used MongoDB) But from what I can tell the `$get_users1` is never empty.

Comment: Try the edited code, the condition should make more sense as it's querying the number of results.

Comment: it's working now, i just use if($get_users1->count()>0). thanks a lot

Comment: Awesome :) a bit hard to try for myself since I don't have that environment to work in, then I learned something new as well :) (forgot to say but your welcome)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116015/discussion-between-diasline-and-sebastian).